# What does O(O(f(n))) mean?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have the understanding about the Big-Oh notation. But how do I interpret what does O(O(f(n))) mean?
Does it mean growth rate of the growth rate?

Comment: Where did you see that? That's not standard notation.

Comment: So, even calculating complexity of an algorithm has a complexity itself?

Comment: In my world, this would only mean something if `O` is a function that accepts a function as it's argument, and that `O` and `f` share signature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`x = O(n)` basically means `x <= kn` for some constant `k`.

Thus `x = O((O(n))` means `x <= pO(n)` for some constant `p`, which means `x <= pqn` for some constant `q`.

Let `k = pq`.

Then `x = O((O(n)) = O(n)`.

In other words, `O(O(f(n))) = O(f(n))`.

I am curious, where did you see such notation being used?

Comment: This is one of the assignments in the university program

Answer (score 1):

From a Big-Oh point of view:

`g(n) = O(f(n))` means `g(n) <= K*f(n)` for some K (and after some n1)

But then `h(n) = O(O(f(n))` would mean something like `h(n) <= L * M * f(n)` for some L, M, after some `n > n1, n2`.

Comment: Which, in turn, means it's simply O(f(n))

Comment: Where the hell do you learn this stuff? I find it somewhat alien, yet fascinating.

Comment: University stuff... Either Mathmatics or Computer Science.